# Executing JavaScript from a Cucumber/Capybara test

Tags: ruby, testing, selenium, cucumber, capybara

It appears that Selenium has a feature called `JavascriptExecutor` which makes it possible to execute JavaScript directly on the page. However it appears that there is no such thing available to my Cucumber/Capybara tests. How can I execute arbitrary JavaScript from my Cucumber tests?

Answer (score 19):

Capybara has two methods to execute javascript #execute_script and #evaluate_script.
Both can be found at: http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Selenium/Driver

However, do note that the readme has this statement about the above methods:

> For simple expressions, you can return the result of the script. Note
>   that this may break with more complicated expressions:

See http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/file/README.md.